# unite 3 Circuitikz Topologys into one Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, circuitikz

following Code:

```
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\documentclass[11pt,
              a4paper,
              DIV=calc
            ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark,markcase=ignoreuppercase,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\automark[section]{chapter}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
% scrartcl ist eine abgeleitete Artikel-Klasse im Koma-Skript
% zur Kontrolle des Umbruchs Klassenoption draft verwenden
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{array,cellspace}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage[]{listofsymbols}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{trees}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,straightvoltages]{circuitikzgit}
\def\coord(#1){coordinate(#1)}
\def\coord(#1){node[circle, red, draw, inner sep=1pt,pin={[red, overlay, inner sep=0.5pt, font=\tiny, pin distance=0.1cm, pin edge={red, overlay,}]45:#1}](#1){}}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,decorations.markings,calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %  Alternativ unter Windows
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\dotfill}
\usepackage[]{listofsymbols}

\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{minted,xcolor}
\usemintedstyle{monokai}
\definecolor{bg}{HTML}{282828}
\setminted{bgcolor=bg}
% Abstand obere Blattkante zur Kopfzeile ist 2.54cm - 15mm
\setlength{\topmargin}{-15mm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\definecolor{tokloGrey}{rgb}{0.68,0.68,0.68}
% Für Zeichnung
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% Schriftgröße der Caption
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
% Microtype - für gleichbleibende Zeilenumbrüche
\usepackage{microtype}
\definecolor{tkblue}{rgb}{0,0.212,0.369}
\definecolor{tkred}{rgb}{1,0.064,0.064}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt} 
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}[H]
      \begin{center}
        \hspace*{-0.5cm}
        \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.75,transform shape] 
        \draw (-1,0) to [short] (11,0);
        \draw (-1,0) to [V<=$U_{\mathrm{in}}$,invert] (-1,4);
        \draw (-1,4) to [short,-*] (2,4);
        % 1. Parallele Zweig
        \draw (2,0) to [C,l=$\mathrm{C_{1}}$,*-*] (2,4);
        \draw (2,4) to [short] (3,4);
        % Horizontaler Zweig
        \draw (3.5,4) to node[nigfete,rotate=90](nigfet){} (3.5,4);
        \draw (nigfet.G) node[anchor=north]{$\mathrm{S_{buck}}$};
        \draw (4.25,4) to [short] (5,4);
        % 2. Parallele Zweig (Diode)
        \draw (5,0) to [D*,l=$\mathrm{D_1}$,*-*] (5,4);
        % Horizontaler Zweig
        \draw (5,4) to [cute inductor,l=$\mathrm{L}$,-*] (8,4);
        % 3. Parallele Zweig (IGBT)
        \draw (8,0) to [short,*-] (8,1.5);
        \draw (8,2) to node[nigbt](nigbt){} (8,2);
        \draw (nigbt.B) node[anchor=east]{$\mathrm{S_{boost}}$};
        \draw (8,2.75) to [short] (8,4);
        % Horizontaler Zweig
        \draw (8,4) to [D*,l=$\mathrm{D_2}$,-*] (11,4);
        % 3. Parallele Zweig
        \draw (11,0) to [C,l=$\mathrm{C_{2}}$,*-*] (11,4);
        % Last-Zweig
        \draw (11,4) to [short,-o] (14,4);
        \draw (11,0) to [short,-o] (14,0);
        \draw[->] (14,3.75) -- (14,0.25);
        \draw (14.25,2) node[anchor=west] {$U_{\mathrm{out}}$};
      \end{circuitikz}
      \label{fig:bi_buck_boost_top}
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{center}
  \hspace*{-0.5cm}
  \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5,transform shape] 
    \draw (-1,0) to [short] (11,0);
    \draw (-1,0) to [V<=$U_{\mathrm{in}}$,invert] (-1,4);
    \draw (-1,4) to [short,-*] (2,4);
    % 1. Parallele Zweig
    \draw (2,0) to [C,l=$\mathrm{C_{1}}$,*-*] (2,4);
    \draw (2,4) to [short] (3,4);
    % Horizontaler Zweig
    \draw (3.5,4) to node[nigfete,rotate=90](nigfet){} (3.5,4);
    \draw (nigfet.G) node[anchor=north]{$\mathrm{S_{buck}}$};
    \draw (4.25,4) to [short] (5,4);
    % 2. Parallele Zweig (Diode)
    \draw (5,0) to [D*,l=$\mathrm{D_1}$,*-*] (5,4);
    % Horizontaler Zweig
    \draw (5,4) to [cute inductor,l=$\mathrm{L}$] (8,4);
    \draw (8,4) to [D*,l=$\mathrm{D_2}$,-*] (11,4);
    % 3. Parallele Zweig
    \draw (11,0) to [C,l=$\mathrm{C_{2}}$,*-*] (11,4);
    % Last-Zweig
    \draw (11,4) to [short,-o] (14,4);
    \draw (11,0) to [short,-o] (14,0);
    \draw[->] (14,3.75) -- (14,0.25);
    \draw (14.25,2) node[anchor=west] {$U_{\mathrm{out}}$};
  \end{circuitikz}
  \label{fig:bi_buck_boost_top}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{center}
    \hspace*{-0.5cm}
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5,transform shape] 
      \draw (-1,0) to [short] (11,0);
      \draw (-1,0) to [V<=$U_{\mathrm{in}}$,invert] (-1,4);
      \draw (-1,4) to [short,-*] (2,4);
      % 1. Parallele Zweig
      \draw (2,0) to [C,l=$\mathrm{C_{1}}$,*-*] (2,4);
      \draw (2,4) to [short] (5,4);
      \draw (5,0) to [D*,l=$\mathrm{D_1}$,*-*] (5,4);
      % Horizontaler Zweig
      \draw (5,4) to [cute inductor,l=$\mathrm{L}$,-*] (8,4);
      \draw (8,0) to [short,*-] (8,1.5);
      \draw (8,2) to node[nigbt](nigbt){} (8,2);
      \draw (nigbt.B) node[anchor=east]{$\mathrm{S_{boost}}$};
      \draw (8,2.75) to [short] (8,4);
      % Horizontaler Zweig
      \draw (8,4) to [D*,l=$\mathrm{D_2}$,-*] (11,4);
      % 3. Parallele Zweig
      \draw (11,0) to [C,l=$\mathrm{C_{2}}$,*-*] (11,4);
      % Last-Zweig
      \draw (11,4) to [short,-o] (14,4);
      \draw (11,0) to [short,-o] (14,0);
      \draw[->] (14,3.75) -- (14,0.25);
      \draw (14.25,2) node[anchor=west] {$U_{\mathrm{out}}$};
  \end{circuitikz}
  \label{fig:bi_buck_boost_top}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

produces following Output:

[image: Topologies]

As you can see, I've used 3 Circuitikz figures to draw each Topology.
My goal is to create an Tikzpicture like this:

[image: Goal]

But I dont know how to get the figures into one new picture, so I can use general Coordinates to create the picture.

edit:Ok, I have embedded my CircuitikZ-picture into an trees-enviroment:

```
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\documentclass[11pt,
              a4paper,
              DIV=calc
            ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark,markcase=ignoreuppercase,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\automark[section]{chapter}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
% scrartcl ist eine abgeleitete Artikel-Klasse im Koma-Skript
% zur Kontrolle des Umbruchs Klassenoption draft verwenden
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{array,cellspace}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage[]{listofsymbols}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{trees}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,straightvoltages]{circuitikzgit}
\def\coord(#1){coordinate(#1)}
\def\coord(#1){node[circle, red, draw, inner sep=1pt,pin={[red, overlay, inner sep=0.5pt, font=\tiny, pin distance=0.1cm, pin edge={red, overlay,}]45:#1}](#1){}}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,decorations.markings,calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %  Alternativ unter Windows
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\dotfill}
\usepackage[]{listofsymbols}

\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{minted,xcolor}
\usemintedstyle{monokai}
\definecolor{bg}{HTML}{282828}
\setminted{bgcolor=bg}
% Abstand obere Blattkante zur Kopfzeile ist 2.54cm - 15mm
\setlength{\topmargin}{-15mm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\definecolor{tokloGrey}{rgb}{0.68,0.68,0.68}
% Für Zeichnung
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% Schriftgröße der Caption
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
% Microtype - für gleichbleibende Zeilenumbrüche
\usepackage{microtype}
\definecolor{tkblue}{rgb}{0,0.212,0.369}
\definecolor{tkred}{rgb}{1,0.064,0.064}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt} 
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [auto]
      \tikzset{
         treenode/.style={align=center, rectangle, draw=black},
         root/.style={treenode, inner sep= 5pt, text width = 12.5cm},
         1/.style={treenode, inner sep= 5pt, text width = 10cm},
         2/.style={treenode, inner sep= 5pt, text width = 1.5cm},
         level1/.style = {sibling distance=11cm, level distance=5.5cm},
         level2/.style = {sibling distance=3cm, level distance=2.5cm}
         }
    
    
      \node[root]{    \begin{figure}[H]
          \begin{center}
            \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.75,transform shape] 
            \draw (-1,0) to [short] (11,0);
            \draw (-1,0) to [V] (-1,4);
            \draw (-1,4) to [short,-*] (2,4);
            % 1. Parallele Zweig
            \draw (2,0) to [C,*-*] (2,4);
            \draw (2,4) to [short] (3,4);
            % Horizontaler Zweig
            \draw (3.5,4) to node[nigfete,rotate=90](nigfet){} (3.5,4);
            %\draw (nigfet.G) node[anchor=north]{$\mathrm{S_{buck}}$};
            \draw (4.25,4) to [short] (5,4);
            % 2. Parallele Zweig (Diode)
            \draw (5,0) to [D*,*-*] (5,4);
            % Horizontaler Zweig
            \draw (5,4) to [cute inductor,-*] (8,4);
            % 3. Parallele Zweig (IGBT)
            \draw (8,0) to [short,*-] (8,1.5);
            \draw (8,2) to node[nigbt](nigbt){} (8,2);
            %\draw (nigbt.B) node[anchor=north]{$\mathrm{S_{boost}}$};
            \draw (8,2.75) to [short] (8,4);
            % Horizontaler Zweig
            \draw (8,4) to [D*,-*] (11,4);
            % 3. Parallele Zweig
            \draw (11,0) to [C,*-*] (11,4);
            % Last-Zweig
            \draw (11,4) to [short,-o] (14,4);
            \draw (11,0) to [short,-o] (14,0);
            \draw[->] (14,3.75) -- (14,0.25);
            %\draw (14.25,2) node[anchor=west] {$U_{\mathrm{out}}$};
          \end{circuitikz}
          \label{fig:bi_buck_boost_top}
        \end{center}
      \end{figure}}
         child[level1]{node[1]{\begin{figure}[H]
          \begin{center}
          \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5,transform shape] 
            \draw (-1,0) to [short] (11,0);
            \draw (-1,0) to [V,invert] (-1,4);
            \draw (-1,4) to [short,-*] (2,4);
            % 1. Parallele Zweig
            \draw (2,0) to [C,*-*] (2,4);
            \draw (2,4) to [short] (3,4);
            % Horizontaler Zweig
            \draw (3.5,4) to node[nigfete,rotate=90](nigfet){} (3.5,4);
            %\draw (nigfet.G) node[anchor=north]{$\mathrm{S_{buck}}$};
            \draw (4.25,4) to [short] (5,4);
            % 2. Parallele Zweig (Diode)
            \draw (5,0) to [D*,*-*] (5,4);
            % Horizontaler Zweig
            \draw (5,4) to [cute inductor] (8,4);
            \draw (8,4) to [D*,-*] (11,4);
            % 3. Parallele Zweig
            \draw (11,0) to [C,*-*] (11,4);
            % Last-Zweig
            \draw (11,4) to [short,-o] (14,4);
            \draw (11,0) to [short,-o] (14,0);
            \draw[->] (14,3.75) -- (14,0.25);
            %\draw (14.25,2) node[anchor=west] {$U_{\mathrm{out}}$};
          \end{circuitikz}
          \label{fig:bi_buck_boost_top}
        \end{center}
        \end{figure}}
            child[level2]{node[2]{$\mathrm{S_{buck:on}}$}}
            child[level2]{node[2]{$\mathrm{S_{buck:off}}$}}}
         child[level1]{node[1]{\begin{figure}[H]
          \begin{center}
            \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5,transform shape] 
              \draw (-1,0) to [short] (11,0);
              \draw (-1,0) to [V,invert] (-1,4);
              \draw (-1,4) to [short,-*] (2,4);
              % 1. Parallele Zweig
              \draw (2,0) to [C,*-*] (2,4);
              \draw (2,4) to [short] (5,4);
              \draw (5,0) to [D*,*-*] (5,4);
              % Horizontaler Zweig
              \draw (5,4) to [cute inductor,-*] (8,4);
              \draw (8,0) to [short,*-] (8,1.5);
              \draw (8,2) to node[nigbt](nigbt){} (8,2);
              %\draw (nigbt.B) node[anchor=north]{$\mathrm{S_{boost}}$};
              \draw (8,2.75) to [short] (8,4);
              % Horizontaler Zweig
              \draw (8,4) to [D*,-*] (11,4);
              % 3. Parallele Zweig
              \draw (11,0) to [C,*-*] (11,4);
              % Last-Zweig
              \draw (11,4) to [short,-o] (14,4);
              \draw (11,0) to [short,-o] (14,0);
              \draw[->] (14,3.75) -- (14,0.25);
              %\draw (14.25,2) node[anchor=west] {$U_{\mathrm{out}}$};
          \end{circuitikz}
          \label{fig:bi_buck_boost_top}
        \end{center}
        \end{figure}}
            child[level2]{node[2]{$\mathrm{S_{boost:on}}$}}
            child[level2]{node[2]{$\mathrm{S_{boost:off}}$}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}    
    \caption{<caption>}
    \label{<label>}
  \end{figure}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image: tree]

But I have no clue how I can implement the Level 4 (Zustandsraum) Nodes, and how to unite them to the Level 5 (SSA)..

Comment: Use `scope`s inside tikzpicture

Comment: `circuitikz` doesn't need to be inside of `circuitikz`-environments, it should work as expected in a `tikzpicture`, too.

Comment: i tried to use nodes in the package trees to set the figures..

Comment: At least for some of us the reason why one may hesitate to write an answer is the huge preamble, which loads a lot of unrelated packages. Even more critically, it loads `circuitikzgit`, which does not seem to be part of TeXLive2019. So could you please cook down the example to a (more) minimal version? BTW, do not use `\node`s to place the circuits unless you put the circuits into `\savebox`es.

Comment: Yes --- as @Schrödinger'scat says, to post questions here please use a much more minimal example. `circuitikzgit` is the "bleeding edge" version, but for your example you can easily use the `circuitikz` distributed with your distro, even if old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One usually strongly recommends to use `\savebox`es when one is to use a `tikzpicture` in a node. This also applies to the contents of `forest` nodes, which I would use to draw this. So the circuits go into `forest` nodes, and the rest is more or less standard with the caveat that the lower part of the tree is drawn by hand since merging branches is not really supported. Other than that I cooked down the example to something considerably more minimal.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark,markcase=ignoreuppercase,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,straightvoltages]{circuitikzgit}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newsavebox\circuiti
\newsavebox\circuitii
\newsavebox\circuitiii
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering\tikzset{medge/.style={thick,-stealth}}
\savebox\circuiti{\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.75,transform shape] 
            \draw (-1,0) to [short] (11,0);
            \draw (-1,0) to [V] (-1,4);
            \draw (-1,4) to [short,-*] (2,4);
            % 1. Parallele Zweig
            \draw (2,0) to [C,*-*] (2,4);
            \draw (2,4) to [short] (3,4);
            % Horizontaler Zweig
            \draw (3.5,4) to node[nigfete,rotate=90](nigfet){} (3.5,4);
            %\draw (nigfet.G) node[anchor=north]{$\mathrm{S_{buck}}$};
            \draw (4.25,4) to [short] (5,4);
            % 2. Parallele Zweig (Diode)
            \draw (5,0) to [D*,*-*] (5,4);
            % Horizontaler Zweig
            \draw (5,4) to [cute inductor,-*] (8,4);
            % 3. Parallele Zweig (IGBT)
            \draw (8,0) to [short,*-] (8,1.5);
            \draw (8,2) to node[nigbt](nigbt){} (8,2);
            %\draw (nigbt.B) node[anchor=north]{$\mathrm{S_{boost}}$};
            \draw (8,2.75) to [short] (8,4);
            % Horizontaler Zweig
            \draw (8,4) to [D*,-*] (11,4);
            % 3. Parallele Zweig
            \draw (11,0) to [C,*-*] (11,4);
            % Last-Zweig
            \draw (11,4) to [short,-o] (14,4);
            \draw (11,0) to [short,-o] (14,0);
            \draw[->] (14,3.75) -- (14,0.25);
            %\draw (14.25,2) node[anchor=west] {$U_{\mathrm{out}}$};
          \end{circuitikz}}%
\savebox\circuitii{\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5,transform shape] 
            \draw (-1,0) to [short] (11,0);
            \draw (-1,0) to [V,invert] (-1,4);
            \draw (-1,4) to [short,-*] (2,4);
            % 1. Parallele Zweig
            \draw (2,0) to [C,*-*] (2,4);
            \draw (2,4) to [short] (3,4);
            % Horizontaler Zweig
            \draw (3.5,4) to node[nigfete,rotate=90](nigfet){} (3.5,4);
            %\draw (nigfet.G) node[anchor=north]{$\mathrm{S_{buck}}$};
            \draw (4.25,4) to [short] (5,4);
            % 2. Parallele Zweig (Diode)
            \draw (5,0) to [D*,*-*] (5,4);
            % Horizontaler Zweig
            \draw (5,4) to [cute inductor] (8,4);
            \draw (8,4) to [D*,-*] (11,4);
            % 3. Parallele Zweig
            \draw (11,0) to [C,*-*] (11,4);
            % Last-Zweig
            \draw (11,4) to [short,-o] (14,4);
            \draw (11,0) to [short,-o] (14,0);
            \draw[->] (14,3.75) -- (14,0.25);
            %\draw (14.25,2) node[anchor=west] {$U_{\mathrm{out}}$};
          \end{circuitikz}}% 
\savebox\circuitiii{\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5,transform shape] 
              \draw (-1,0) to [short] (11,0);
              \draw (-1,0) to [V,invert] (-1,4);
              \draw (-1,4) to [short,-*] (2,4);
              % 1. Parallele Zweig
              \draw (2,0) to [C,*-*] (2,4);
              \draw (2,4) to [short] (5,4);
              \draw (5,0) to [D*,*-*] (5,4);
              % Horizontaler Zweig
              \draw (5,4) to [cute inductor,-*] (8,4);
              \draw (8,0) to [short,*-] (8,1.5);
              \draw (8,2) to node[nigbt](nigbt){} (8,2);
              %\draw (nigbt.B) node[anchor=north]{$\mathrm{S_{boost}}$};
              \draw (8,2.75) to [short] (8,4);
              % Horizontaler Zweig
              \draw (8,4) to [D*,-*] (11,4);
              % 3. Parallele Zweig
              \draw (11,0) to [C,*-*] (11,4);
              % Last-Zweig
              \draw (11,4) to [short,-o] (14,4);
              \draw (11,0) to [short,-o] (14,0);
              \draw[->] (14,3.75) -- (14,0.25);
              %\draw (14.25,2) node[anchor=west] {$U_{\mathrm{out}}$};
          \end{circuitikz}}%          
    \begin{forest}
     forked edges,
     for tree={anchor=center,
            edge={medge},
            l sep=2em,  
            fork sep=1em,
            font=\sffamily,
            text depth=0.25ex,
            execute at begin node=\strut
    }
     [\usebox\circuiti,alias=i
      [\usebox\circuitii,alias=ii
       [on,alias=on
        [$\vec X_\mathrm{pft}$,alias=pft1]
       ]
       [off
        [$\vec X_\mathrm{pft}$,alias=pft2]
       ]
       ]
      [\usebox\circuitiii
       [on
        [$\vec X_\mathrm{pft}$,alias=pft3]
       ]
       [off
        [$\vec X_\mathrm{pft}$,alias=pft4]
       ]
       ]
     ]
    \begin{scope}[font=\sffamily]
      \path (pft1.south) -- (pft2.south) node[midway,below=2em](bulk) 
          {$\langle\vec X_\mathrm{bulk}\rangle$};
      \path (pft3.south) -- (pft4.south) node[midway,below=2em](boost) 
          {$\langle\vec X_\mathrm{boost}\rangle$};
      \draw[medge] (pft1.south) -- ++ (0,-1em) -| (bulk);
      \draw[medge] (pft2.south) -- ++ (0,-1em) -| (bulk);
      \draw[medge] (pft3.south) -- ++ (0,-1em) -| (boost);
      \draw[medge] (pft4.south) -- ++ (0,-1em) -| (boost);
      \node[below left=2em and 1em of bulk.south] (stat) {station\"are W.};
      \node[below right=2em and 1em of bulk.south] (Lin1) {Linearisiering};
      \node[below left=2em and 1em of boost.south] (nix) {station\"are W.};
      \node[below right=2em and 1em of boost.south] (Lin2) {Linearisiering};
      \draw[medge] (bulk)   -- (stat);
      \draw[medge] (bulk)   -- (Lin1);
      \draw[medge] (boost)  -- (nix);
      \draw[medge] (boost)  -- (Lin2);
      \path (current bounding box.west) coordinate[left=1em] (L); 
      % 
      \path (L|-i) node[left]{Kaskadiert};
      \path (L|-ii) node[left]{Topologie};
      \path (L|-on) node[left]{Schaltzust\"ande};
      \path (L|-pft1) node[left]{Zustandsraum};
      \path (L|-bulk) node[left]{SSA};
    \end{scope}
    \end{forest}    
    \caption{Some caption.}
    \label{fig:3circuits}
  \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thats a nice solution! I will work through it and trying to understand!

Answer (score 3):

Nesting `tikzpicture`s is normally frowned upon (search for "nesting tikzpicture" here...), because the results are not guaranteed.

In these cases, when the circuit has to be repeated, I usually define a macro to draw the circuit relative to a parameter which is a coordinate. Into the macro, I define a set of `coordinate`s that are then useful to build the rest of the diagram.

The following is just a small example, but I hope it can give an idea.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usectikzstyle{romano}
\newcommand{\mycirc}[3][]{% define the circuit relative to the (external)
    % coordinate; use as  \mycirc[options]{coord}{name}
    % it will define the coordinate nw-name, sw-name etc. for further references
    \begin{scope}[#1]
        \draw #2 coordinate (start)
        to[V] ++(0,2) to[short, *-*]
        ++(2,0) coordinate(R) to [D] (R|-start)
        to [short, *-*] (start);
        \path (start) ++(-1,-1) coordinate(sw-#3)
        (R) ++(1,1) coordinate (ne-#3)
        (sw-#3 |- ne-#3) coordinate (nw-#3)
        (sw-#3 -| ne-#3) coordinate (se-#3);
        \draw [thin] (sw-#3) rectangle (ne-#3);
    \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \mycirc{(0,0)}{top}
    \mycirc[scale=0.7, transform shape]{(-5,-7)}{left}
    \mycirc[scale=0.7, transform shape]{(6,-7)}{right}
    \draw[red] ([yshift=-0.2cm]$(sw-top)!0.5!(se-top)$) -- ++(0,-0.5) coordinate(a);
    \draw [red,->] (a) -| ([yshift=0.2cm]$(nw-left)!0.5!(ne-left)$);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat yes, but sometimes `pic`s have problems with `circuitikz` (not sure why; I suppose that the un-rotation algorithms for labels and some parts wreak havoc with the normal path code... :-))