# Double bended arrows in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

following Code:

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\definecolor{tokloGrey}{rgb}{0.68,0.68,0.68}
\definecolor{tkblue}{rgb}{0,0.212,0.369}
\definecolor{tkred}{rgb}{1,0.064,0.064}
\newcommand{\A}{\underline{\mathrm{A}}}
\newcommand{\B}{\underline{\mathrm{B}}}
\newcommand{\bv}{\vec{\mathrm{b}}}
\newcommand{\bz}{\vec{\mathrm{b_z}}}
\newcommand{\CM}{\underline{\mathrm{C}}}
\newcommand{\D}{\underline{\mathrm{D}}}
% Zustandsvektor
\newcommand{\zv}{\dot{\vec{\mathrm{x}}}}
\newcommand{\xv}{\vec{\mathrm{x}}}
% Zustandsgrößen
\newcommand{\uC}[1]{\mathrm{u_{C_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\iL}{\mathrm{i_L}}
% Reglervariablen
\newcommand{\K}[1]{\mathrm{k_{#1}}}
\newcommand{\kT}{\vec{\mathrm{k}}^{\mathrm{T}}}
\newcommand{\cT}{\vec{\mathrm{c}}^{\mathrm{T}}}
\newcommand{\edot}{\dot{\mathrm{e}}}
\newcommand{\uS}[1]{\mathrm{u_{#1}}(\mathrm{t})}
\newcommand{\w}{\mathrm{w}(\mathrm{t})}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
     input/.style={coordinate},
     block/.style={draw, fill=white!20,rectangle,minimum height=2em,minimum width=2em},
     sum/.style={draw,fill=white!20,circle,node distance=1.25cm},
     output/.style={coordinate},
     x0/.style = {coordinate},
     pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}},
     dot/.style = {circle,fill,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1pt}
     }

\begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=1.75cm,>=latex',scale=0.04]
            \node [input, name=input] (input) {$\mathrm{w}$};
            \node [sum,right of=input] (esum) {};
            % PI-Regler
            \node [block, right of=esum] (kI) {$\bigintssss$};
            \node [block, above of=kI] (kP) {$\mathrm{k_p}$};
            \node [block, right of=kI] (integrale) {$\mathrm{k_i}$};
            \node [sum,right of=integrale] (usum) {};
            \node [sum,right of=usum] (usum2) {};
            \node [block, right of=usum2] (b) {$\B$};
            \node [sum, right of=b] (sum) {};
            \node [block, right of=sum] (integralx) {$\bigintssss$};
            \node [block, right of=integralx] (c) {$\vec{\mathrm{c}}^{\mathrm{T}}$};
            \node [block, below of=integralx] (A) {$\A$};
            \node [block, below of=A] (kT) {$\mathrm{k_1}$};
            \node [block, below of=kT] (kT2) {$\mathrm{k_2}$};
            \node [output, name=output,right of=c,node distance=1.25cm] (output) {};


            \draw[->] (input) -- node[name=u,align=left,below,font=\scriptsize] {$\mathrm{w}$} (esum);
            \draw[->] (esum) -- node[name=edot,below,font=\scriptsize] {$\dot{\mathrm{e}}$} (kI);
            \draw[->] (edot) |- (kP);
            \draw[->] (kP) -| node[pos=0.99,left,font=\tiny] {$+$} (usum);
            \draw[->] (kI) -- node[name=e,below] {} (integrale);
            \draw[->] (integrale) -- node[name=uPI,below] {} (usum);
            \draw[->] (usum2) -- node[name=u,above,font=\scriptsize] {$\mathrm{u}$} (b);
            \draw[->] (usum) -- node[name=uPI,above,font=\scriptsize] {$\mathrm{u_{PI}}$} (usum2);
            \draw[->] (b) -- (sum);
            \draw[->] (sum) -- node[name=xdot,font=\scriptsize] {$\Delta\dot{\vec{x}}$} (integralx);
            \draw[->] (integralx) -- node[name=x,font=\scriptsize] {$\Delta\vec{x}$} (c);
            \draw[->] (x) |- (A);
            \draw[->] (x) |- node[pos=0.745,above,font=\tiny] {\tiny$\Delta\iL$} (kT);
            \draw[->] (x) |- node[pos=0.5,below,font=\tiny] {\tiny$\Delta\uC{2}$} (kT2);
            \draw[->] (kT) -| node[pos=0.99,font=\tiny] {$+$}  node[pos=0.99,right,font=\scriptsize] {$\mathrm{u_{ZR}}$} (usum2);
            \draw[->] (kT2) -|  (usum2);
            \draw[->] (A) -| node[pos=0.99,font=\tiny] {\tiny$+$} (sum);
            \draw[->] (c) -- node[name=y,align=center,above,font=\scriptsize] {$\mathrm{y}$} (output);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \label{abb:strukturbild_Zustandsraum}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

produces following Image:

[image]

but I want an Arrow from $y$ to the sum after $w$ like this:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: It is very easy to answer the question. However, it is cumbersome to clean up. Could you please replace all the `\tikzstyle` stuff by the corresponding `\tikzset` syntax, and remove all unnecessary stuff?

Comment: I have removed all the unnecessary stuff so far, but dont get what you mean by replacing the \tikzstyle with \tikzset. I mean, with that Im only defining my Objects, why should I use the other syntax?

Comment: It would be great if you could use the `\tikzset` syntax that you used e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/515656/194703). Also, there should not be a `[tikz]` in `\documentclass[tikz]{article}`, this key is defined e.g. for `standalone` but not `article`. Also your figure is too big for the settings of your document. So if someone comes, answers the question, cleans up and forgets to fix one minor detail, someone else will come, copy the code, fix the minor detail, and get the full credit. This is why questions which require major repair aren't as popular as they could be.

Comment: okay! I have edited the Code.

Comment: I am so sorry to bug you again and you may find this nasty, but this is an attempt to help. **Never** define single-letter macros like `\newcommand{\A}{\underline{\mathrm{A}}}`. Specify the font information of nodes via `font=\tiny`, say, instead of putting `\tiny` at the begin of the node. Do *not* use the deprecated way of positioning nodes, rather use the `positioning` library with its corresponding syntax. This is really not to annoy you, but to spare you from major problems later on.

Comment: Hehe no problem. Im here to learn and not to get things done! I have edited the fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the main question is very simple: put the diagram except for the arrow you are asking for in a local bounding box (called `diagram` here) and add

```
\draw[->] (y|-c) |- ([yshift=-1em]diagram.south) -| (esum);
```

In principle you do not even need a `local bounding box`, you could work with the `current bounding box` instead, but I find this practice cleaner.

Then there are some of off-topic changes and suggestions in addition to those in the comments above:

1. Your figure is too wide for the standard article class and you cannot use a `figure` environment in a `standalone` class. Current fix: make the page wider with the `geometry` package.
2. Please use the `positioning` library. Instead of `below of=<node>` you can now say `below=<distance> of <node>`, where `distance` is really the vertical space that emerges. I did these changes.
3. Do not define one-letter macros. This can have severe side-effects, e.g. when you compile with another engine such as `xelatex`. It is just bad practice.

Here is the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}%<- added
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}%<- changed
\usepackage{bigints}
\definecolor{tokloGrey}{rgb}{0.68,0.68,0.68}
\definecolor{tkblue}{rgb}{0,0.212,0.369}
\definecolor{tkred}{rgb}{1,0.064,0.064}
\newcommand{\uC}[1]{\mathrm{u_{C_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\iL}{\mathrm{i_L}}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{% maybe better define these locally but OK
     input/.style={coordinate},
     block/.style={draw, fill=white!20,rectangle,minimum height=2em,minimum width=2em},
     sum/.style={draw,fill=white!20,circle,node distance=1.25cm},
     output/.style={coordinate},
     x0/.style = {coordinate},
     pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}},
     dot/.style = {circle,fill,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1pt}
     }

\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=1cm,>=Latex]
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=diagram]
     \node [input, name=input] (input) {$\mathrm{w}$};
     \node [sum,right=of input] (esum) {};
     % PI-Regler
     \node [block, right=of esum] (kI) {$\bigintssss$};
     \node [block, above=of kI] (kP) {$\mathrm{k_p}$};
     \node [block, right=of kI] (integrale) {$\mathrm{k_i}$};
     \node [sum,right=of integrale] (usum) {};
     \node [sum,right=of usum] (usum2) {};
     \node [block, right=of usum2] (b) {$\underline{\mathrm{B}}$};
     \node [sum, right=of b] (sum) {};
     \node [block, right=of sum] (integralx) {$\bigintssss$};
     \node [block, right=of integralx] (c) {$\vec{\mathrm{c}}^{\mathrm{T}}$};
     \node [block, below=of integralx] (A) {$\underline{\mathrm{A}}$};
     \node [block, below=of A] (kT) {$\mathrm{k_1}$};
     \node [block, below=of kT] (kT2) {$\mathrm{k_2}$};
     \node [output, name=output,right=1.25cm of c] (output) {};


     \draw[->] (input) -- node[name=u,align=left,below,font=\scriptsize] {$\mathrm{w}$} (esum);
     \draw[->] (esum) -- node[name=edot,below,font=\scriptsize] {$\dot{\mathrm{e}}$} (kI);
     \draw[->] (edot) |- (kP);
     \draw[->] (kP) -| node[pos=0.99,left,font=\tiny] {$+$} (usum);
     \draw[->] (kI) -- node[name=e,below] {} (integrale);
     \draw[->] (integrale) -- node[name=uPI,below] {} (usum);
     \draw[->] (usum2) -- node[name=u,above,font=\scriptsize] {$\mathrm{u}$} (b);
     \draw[->] (usum) -- node[name=uPI,above,font=\scriptsize] {$\mathrm{u_{PI}}$} (usum2);
     \draw[->] (b) -- (sum);
     \draw[->] (sum) -- node[name=xdot,font=\scriptsize] {$\Delta\dot{\vec{x}}$} (integralx);
     \draw[->] (integralx) -- node[name=x,font=\scriptsize] {$\Delta\vec{x}$} (c);
     \draw[->] (x) |- (A);
     \draw[->] (x) |- node[pos=0.745,above,font=\tiny] {$\Delta\mathrm{i_L}$} (kT);
     \draw[->] (x) |- node[pos=0.5,below,font=\tiny] {\tiny$\Delta\uC{2}$} (kT2);
     \draw[->] (kT) -| node[pos=0.99,font=\tiny] {$+$}  node[pos=0.99,right,font=\scriptsize] {$\mathrm{u_{ZR}}$} (usum2);
     \draw[->] (kT2) -|  (usum2);
     \draw[->] (A) -| node[pos=0.99,font=\tiny] {\tiny$+$} (sum);
     \draw[->] (c) -- node[name=y,align=center,above,font=\scriptsize] {$\mathrm{y}$} (output);
     %
  \end{scope}    
  \draw[->] (y|-c) |- ([yshift=-1em]diagram.south) -| (esum);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \label{abb:strukturbild_Zustandsraum}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is obvious that one can improve the figure quite a bit. These are some first steps. I would appreciate if not the standard story repeats itself here. Some user shows up, copies the code, makes a few minor changes, and gets the full credit. This discourages whoever makes the first steps.

Comment: Thanks for your time! Can you explain why u set the bended arrow outer the scope-enviroment?

Comment: @adaptive Sure. The `local bounding box` allows us to find out how large the diagram is before we start drawing the arrow. Then `([yshift=-1em]diagram.south)` is just `1em` below the smallest y coordinate of the diagram so far, and this allows us to avoid collisions without hard-coding some values. In particular, if you change the diagram, the arrow will also adjust.